# Is there any shortest and safe path algorithm taking total number of accidents as parameter better then Dijkstra algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, shortest-path, dijkstra, recommendation-engine, floyd-warshall

This question is for my final year project. This project is all about the recommendation of a safe route to the user to avoid accident-prone street. For this purpose, we are looking for an algorithm which has better time complexity as well as space complexity than the Dijsta.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can phrase this problem as:

- finding a path
- in a directed graph
- with non-negative weights

You can solve it with Thorup [2004]
This particular algorithm claims to perform in O(E + V * log log V)

An example implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/npruehs/thorup)

Comment: Could you elaborate on the algorithm implementation in your answer?: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: So far now we are looking at a* algorithm.We are planning to make a website  in python using geodjango framework. The main feature of our website would be safe routing recommendation on openstreetmap using A* algorithm which avoids obstacles like streets which has maximum accident numbers and high risk of accident on time bases. But we are enable to find the code of A* algorithm which implements on map. Please help and ignore any grammatical errors if any